# Agrupar por 4, 10, y 20

Tags: php, bucle-for, while

Como puedo agruparlos por 16, porque solo me arroja toda la lista nada más.

```
<?php
$connect = new mysqli(
  "localhost",
  "healtha2_syste26",
  "*********",
  "healtha2_iyf"
  ) or die (mysqli_error());

$query=$connect->query(
  "SELECT Nombre, Edad, Sexo, Grupo, Hospedaje
   FROM registros
   WHERE edad BETWEEN 11 AND 17 
     AND Sexo = 'FEMENINO'
     AND Hospedaje = 'Si'
   ORDER BY Hospedaje "
);

$first_fetch=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//echo $first_fetch['Nombre']."===>".$first_fetch['Grupo']."\n--------------------\n";

while($row=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  echo $row['Nombre'] . "  " . $row['Edad'] . "  " . 
    $row['Sexo'] . "  " . $row['Grupo'] . "  " . 
    $row['Hospedaje'] . "<br/>"; 
  for ($row = 1; $row <= 16; $row++){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El operador módulo [`%`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.arithmetic.php) puede ser de ayuda:

```
$idx = 0;
while( $row = $query->fetch_array( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){
  $idx++;
  echo $idx . ") ".
    $row['Nombre'] . "  " . $row['Edad'] . "  " .
    $row['Sexo'] . "  " . $row['Grupo'] . "  " .
    $row['Hospedaje'] . "<br/>".PHP_EOL;
  if ( 0 == $idx % 4 ) {
    echo PHP_EOL.'<hr/>'.PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @aloMalbarez